# How to organize css files in a Joomla 2.5 template?

Tags: css, file, templates, joomla

I want to design a template for Joomla 2.5, but i don't know how to organize my own css files correctly and clearly.

Taking **Beez_20** as an example, my questions is..

*Why they decided to create css files such as 
`general.css`,`layout.css`, `position.css`,`template.css`?*

*What's the use of each file?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Joomla templates are al you can probably imagine, rather big. Especially ones that are developed by big companies such as Yootheme and Rockettheme. Putting the styling into 1 CSS file would make the file massive and if trying to edit some of the code, it makes life easier if the file is smaller as it doesn't contain as much code.

For example, if you want to edit the styling for a module, you know instantly it will be in ***module.css*** and finding the exact like will hardly take any time.

**Update:**

- **general.css** = buttons, images, error messages etc.
- **position.css** = positioning, widths and height main blocks such as the header, content etc.
- **layout.css** = styling in more detail such as inputs, labels, buttons etc.
- **modules.css (not default Joomla template)** = positioning and styling for module positions
- **ieonly** = specific fixed for IE browsers
- **nature.css** = font families, font colours etc
- **print.css** = styling for the site when in print preview.
- **template.ccs** = standard styling for the body tag and and defining no borders for images.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank Lodder! However, can you explain specifically how we organize css files correctly and clearly. For example, **layout.css** to adjust _size of wrappers,font-size_,..., **color.css** to adjust _color_,..etc, Thank again!

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Lodder; maintainability is the main reason.

But this is not acceptable in production (you can't download 8 css files, it's a nice way to kill page load time).  So after testing is complete you should switch to

1. compressed file (use jsmin or similar to pack the files together)
2. add a "custom.css" so your users can put their overrides there without messing with the huge file